# CORS Issue: Is npm cors module formatting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" field correctly in my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to set up a React frontend to send an Axios request to an Express backend. Localhost:3000 contains my React app, and localhost:3001 contains my Express app. I am doing an Axios request as follows on the React side:

```
axios.get('localhost:3001/')
```

However, I am getting the following error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3001/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I've imported the npm cors module to my Express backend, and used it as follows:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

However, my React application still runs into the same CORS issue.

I checked the res object by console.logging res into the terminal, and saw that cors() is modifying the http header as follows:

```
...
 [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
  [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
     'access-control-allow-origin': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' ] } }
```

Is access-control-allow-origin supposed to take a list value? Ultimately, I wish to fix my React CORS issue, and am wondering if this is expected behavior.

Comment: What do the response headers look like in the browser, and what do your `app` routes look like? Also try setting up the cors to handle the Options request as you might be using ajax requests that require a preflight check which the simple method of that module arent setup for by default, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: The express app you displayed, is it the one outputting your react app, or the one presenting the api the react app is accessing?

Comment: Since it looks like your main issue is with express and not axios and react, you can try rephrasing the question to remove those other frameworks. In Chrome DevTools, what do you see in the Network panel after you enter `fetch('http://localhost:3001')` in the Console panel?

Comment: @interestinglythere after I do the fetch command as suggested, and analyzing the request in the Network panel, it seems that the response has the correctly formatted headers in the browser:

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: So it seems like my CORS error is not from the cors module... I will try setting up cors to handle the Options request as @Patrick Evans suggested, and see how that goes.

Comment: @KevinB It would be the latter case (the express app is presenting the api that the react app is accessing).

Comment: You elided the actual error message. The important part for others here to know is actually the part that comes after *“has been blocked by CORS policy”* in the error message. What exactly does that part say?

Comment: @slideshowbarker I've edited the post. It went on to say: "...Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> axios.get('localhost:3001/')
> ```

You are trying to make a request to the server named `3001` using the communications scheme `localhost`.

You probably want `axios.get('http://localhost:3001/')`

Comment: Oh wow... I really overlooked that one. This fixed my problem like a charm! Thanks @Quentin